# How to rotate 3D vector by 3d angle?

Tags: java, android, sensor-fusion

I have an array with XYZ values from accelerometer and I have problem, that the axies are chanhing relative to world coordinates. I also have gyroscope, that thru some calculations I am making returns an angle in radians. The qestion is how to align accelerometer axies to world coordinates. O have googled, but I could only find vector mathematics or matricies, that I cannot recreate in android app, that I am making.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: A matrix calculation is just a series of scalar operations, so you could use the matrix solution you found on Google by converting it into a series of scalar formulae. Alternatively, use trigonometry and work out your own solution from first principles. If you don't want to program your own solution you could instead use an open source linear algebra library. Also, there is a problem with using angles to rotate objects called Gimbal Lock - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock#In_applied_mathematics

Comment: Thanx. Did not thought about it (We did not have matricses in school yet).